# Чистка списка на элементы которые невозможно записать Python

Tags: python

Час добрый
Подскажите каким образом можно удалить из списка элементы которые не поддаются обработке во время записи в файл. Как пример, следующая строка:

```
list = ['Пример ♥ строки с ошибочным элементом для записи', 'пример чистой строки']
```

То есть чтобы во время записи командой:

```
with open('data_file.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='cp1252') as csvfile:
```

Все элементы (в данном случае ♥) которые выдают ошибку расшифровки были удалены из строки. 
Единственное как могу представить решение проблемы - устроить проверку на каждый символ элемента в списке. Что-то по типу следующего:

```
    for line in list:
        line_strip = line.split()
        for el in line_strip:
            try:
                with open('data_file_check.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                    Сохраняем файл с постоянной перезаписью, чтобы не забивать файл лишним 
                    
            except Exception as ex:
                print(f'[INFO] Возникла следующая ошибка: {ex}')
                pass
```

На моменте проверки в блоке try: должно происходить сохранение элемента в новую переменную (скажем edited_list), а в случае ошибки - просто пропускать элемент. Далее уже отсортированный список объединить при помощи join и сохранять в итоговый файл. Однако такой список после объединения не будет содержать нужной целостности с разделителями в нужных местах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто при помощи параметра `errors=` укажите функции `open()` как себя вести в случае невозможности преобразования символа.

```
with open('data_file.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='cp1251', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
```

Например, если указать `"ignore"`, то не поддерживаемые символы будут отброшены.
Другие варианты см. в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

P.S. И в `cp1252` от ваших строк останутся только пробелы.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)